# Are questions about gold panning as a hobby or sport on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions about gold panning as a hobby or sport on-topic at The Great Outdoors?

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: Only if you do it outdoors. ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, absolutely!

> The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange is for people who love outdoor
>   activities, excursions, and outdoorsmanship.

https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

- Outdoor activity: It's an activity and you have to do it outdoors
- Excursions: You have to go somewhere unusual (possibly even more or less into the wild) to do it
- Outdoorsmanship: If you look at it from an American perspective, it's even one of the most fundamental outdoorsmanship-things (just like hunting, fishing etc.)

There are even already [questions on this site](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/search?q=gold%20panning) (or at least one :D).

Comment: I agree but an excursion doesn't have to be out into the wild, but it is a great word for 'going out on a leisure trip to somewhere'! :D

Comment: @Aravona Better? :)

Comment: Absolutely wonderful, great answer ;)